# asp:boundfield dataformatstring not working

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I am working on a vb.net web application and I am displaying a Gridview with rows containing datetime, the data is coming from database. In my aspx file, within my asp:boundfield I am trying to change the date format (which at the moment is mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss) to "dd MMM yyyy" (no time) and I have tried using the dataformatstring and HtmlEncode="True/False" (both) but still it does not change the date format in the GridView. The code is as shown below -

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="STF_JOINED" HeaderText="Joined" SortExpression="STF_JOINED" HtmlEncode="False" DataFormatString = "{0:d}" ReadOnly="True">
```

In the above code I tried to format the date to shortdate for the moment but it didn't work. I would still want the date format to be in "dd MMM yyyy" format.

I have tried a number of solutions from stackoverflow but none of them seem to work for me. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong or what I should be doing, by giving a small example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `HtmlEncode` at all.

For `DataFormatString` You have to use, for example, `{0:dd MM yyyy}` or `{0:dd.MM.yyyy}` beacuse Your database field data type is `datetime` not `date` (where `dd` represent day, `MM` month and `yyyy` year. Be aware for `MM`, if You write `mm` it's represent minutes).

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="STF_JOINED" HeaderText="Joined" SortExpression="STF_JOINED" DataFormatString = "{0:dd MM yyyy}" ReadOnly="True">
```

Tested and working.

You can read more about data format strings here : [BoundField.DataFormatString Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

There You can see examples for *Standard and Custom format string* (links under every table).

Comment: nelek, I just tried adding DataFormatString = "{0:dd MM yyyy}" to my boundfield but it didn't work. Also just to be sure I made a plain vanilla page for this from scratch. I want to ask at this point is there any other settings in VS2012 or Windows that I need to do in order for this to work. Also could you pls show a complete aspx page code so that I can cross verify with my page.

Comment: nelek, I found out why I was wasn't able to change the the data format. Seems like someone changed the column type to varchar in that particular database table. After reverting the columns back to datetime type I was able to make the data format work. Thank you for your help ....